# How i can get how many times i have to rotate binary input to make it in original form in c#

Tags: c#, input, rotation

I need to count how many times a binary input needs to rotate to get its original form again
for example
if i enter 10101 it needs for rotation to 5 cyclic shifts to become 10101 again
if i enter 010101 it needs for rotation to 2 cyclic shifts to become 010101 again
or
if i enter 111111 or 000000 it needs  1 cyclic shifts to become 111111 or 000000  again

my code

```
using System;
class Solution
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var binarayInput = Console.ReadLine();
      var a = binarayInput;
      var b = binarayInput[^1] + binarayInput[..^1];
      Console.WriteLine(b);
    
      var count = 0;

      while(a !=b){
         b = binarayInput[^1] + binarayInput[..^1];
         count ++;
      }
      
      Console.WriteLine(count);
   }
}
```

Comment: string binarayInput = "11101";
            binarayInput = binarayInput.Substring(1) + binarayInput.Substring(0,1);

Comment: i don't want to rotate i want to count number of rotation's

Comment: Put my code in while loop instead of yours.

Comment: Nothing happening..

Comment: Impossible.  You are stuck in the while loop.  The while is testing 'b' and inside the while loop you are always using same input.  While loop should contains : b =  b.Substring(1) + b.Substring(0,1);

Comment: *10101 it needs for rotation to 4 cyclic shifts* - er. I think you'll have to shift it 5 times

Comment: What is your question? PS I take it by "rotate" you mean rotate to the right?

Comment: "Caius Jard" , thanks i have edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach:

We take the string, concatenate it onto itself once and then ask what the first index of the original string is in the new string (starting at 1; if we started at 0 it would always match because zero shifts always matches):

```
var s = "10101";

var shiftsNeeded = (s+s).IndexOf(s, 1);
```

It works like:

```
"1010110101".IndexOf("10101", 1)

Start at 1:

1010110101
 10101       -> index 1? no

1010110101
  10101      -> index 2? no

1010110101
   10101     -> index 3? no

1010110101
    10101    -> index 4? no

1010110101
     10101   -> index 5? yes
```

Comment: Very brilliant!

Comment: Elegant and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string originalInput = Console.ReadLine()+string.Empty;

Console.WriteLine($"Input: {originalInput}");

string current = string.Join(string.Empty, originalInput.Select(c => c));
for(var i=0; i<originalInput.Length; i+=1) {
    var temp = CyclicShift(current);
    Console.WriteLine($"Shift {i+1}: {temp}");
    if(originalInput.Equals(temp)) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Become original after {i+1} shifts.");
        break;
    }
    current = temp;
}

string CyclicShift(string input) {
    if(input.Length == 0) return string.Empty;
    if(input.Length == 1) return input;

    var newStr = input[^1] + input[..^1];
    return newStr;
}
```

Test:

```
Input: 10101
Shift 1: 11010
Shift 2: 01101
Shift 3: 10110
Shift 4: 01011
Shift 5: 10101
Become original after 5 shifts.

Input: 010101
Shift 1: 101010
Shift 2: 010101
Become original after 2 shifts.

Input: 111111
Shift 1: 111111
Become original after 1 shifts.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 6, you could take the advantage of [`.TakeLast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takelast?view=net-6.0) and [`.SkipLast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=net-6.0) from `System.Linq` when temporarily "building" your rotated string.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Solution
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        var binaryInput = Console.ReadLine();

        var shifts = 1;
        
        while (binaryInput != string.Join("", binaryInput.TakeLast(shifts).Concat(binaryInput.SkipLast(shifts))))
        {
            shifts++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(shifts);
   }
}
```

When e.g. `shifts == 3`, `binaryInput.TakeLast(shifts)` will take the 3 last chars of `binaryInput` (converted to an `IEnumerable<char>`, because that is the return value of `.TakeLast()` when it is called on a `string`), and `binaryInput.SkipLast(shifts)` will take all the chars of `binaryInput` *but* the three last (also converted to an `IEnumerable<char>`).

To stitch the two `IEnumerable<char>`s back together to a string again, I am using `.Concat()` to merge them into one `IEnumerable<char>`, and then `string.Join()` to convert it to a string that can be compared with `binaryInput`.

---

Fiddle to try it out [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/25F757).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make so much as one single substring/one extra allocation operation to complete this.

This method tests if a string shifted (right) by `offset` is equal to the string:

```
bool CircularEquals(string s, int offset){
  for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    if(s[i] != s[(i+offset) % s.Length])
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

It works by conceptually establishing two pointers to the chars in the string and advancing them each by one. When the "shifted right" pointer falls off the end of the string a modulo wraps it around again

e.g. a shift of 2:

```
10101
^
  ^       1 == 1, loop continues

10101
 ^
   ^      0 == 0, loop continues

10101
  ^
    ^     1 == 1, loop continues

10101
   ^
^         0 != 1, returns false. 10101 doesn't work if shifted 2
```

You can test each shift:

```
    var s = "10101";
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= s.Length; i++){
      if(CircularEquals(s,i))
         Console.WriteLine("String " + s + " is identical after " + i + " shifts");
    }
```